# How to multiple replace string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like :

```
id  name        percent
-----------------------
1   John        %01
2   Doe         %02
3   2015-07-23  %03
4   testAdress  %04
5   ......      ...

declare @tbl TABLE (id int, name varchar(500), [percent] char(3))

INSERT INTO @tbl (id, name, [percent])
    SELECT 1, 'John', '%01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Doe', '%02'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2015-07-23', '%03'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'testAdress', '%04'
```

And have text like

```
declare @text varchar(max) = 
     '<p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">My Header: </font>TEXT</p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">FirstName: %01</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">LastName: %02</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Datetime: %03</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Address: %04</font></p></font></p>'`
```

Now I want to replace all percents in text to name which I have in my table.

Table can have many names with different percents and text also can have many percents, for example I take only 4. The response must be like :

```
'<p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">My Header: </font>TEXT</p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">FirstName: John</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">LastName: Doe</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Datetime: 2015-07-23</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Address: testAdress</font></p></font></p>'
```

How to do it? I try nested `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE ....` but it is not good idea if I must replace 50 or 100 percents.

**Edit:**

I try something like this :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@text,'%01', (SELECT name FROM @tbl WHERE [percent] = '%01')),'%02',(SELECT name FROM @tbl WHERE [percent] = '%02'))
```

But I have in text from %01 to %99 and cant write 99 replace for one variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @txt VARCHAR(MAX) = '<p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">My Header: </font>TEXT</p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">FirstName: %01</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">LastName: %02</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Datetime: %03</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Address: %04</font></p></font></p>'
```

---

Try this:

```
SELECT @txt = REPLACE(@txt, [percent], ISNULL(name, ''))                       
FROM @tbl
WHERE CHARINDEX([percent], @txt) > 0

SELECT @txt
```

Output

```
<p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">My Header: </font>TEXT</p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">FirstName: John</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">LastName: Doe</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Datetime: 2015-07-23</font></p>  <p align=\"left\"><font size=\"1\">Address: testAdress</font></p></font></p>
```

Comment: thank you it works for me, can you explain please this part : `WHERE CHARINDEX([percent], @txt) > 0`  It find all percents in txt ?

Comment: It is just to check if that replaced text is in the original text or not.